# Unable to import module from current path in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on flask project which is in python3.4, my project structure is like below,

```
|-- venv
|-- web
  |--admin
     |--settings
       |--custom_settings.py
  |--script.py
```

Here venv folder is python3 virtual env with flask & etc modules installed.

in script.py file, i am trying to import module from settings package as below,

```
from admin.settings.custom_settings import db, Role, Users
```

but when i try to execute the script i am getting error

```
user@mint ~/PRJ/web $ ../../venv/bin/python3 script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 23, in <module>
from admin.settings.custom_settings import db, Role, User
File "/home/user/PRJ/web/admin/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
admin.settings.custom_settings import db, Role, User
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

output from sys.path

```
/home/user/PRJ/admin/web
/home/user/PRJ/admin
/home/user/PRJ/venv/lib/python3.4
/home/user/PRJ/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/user/PRJ/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.4
/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/user/PRJ/venv/lib/python3.4/site-package
```

Please let me know what what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `import admin; print(admin.__file__)` give?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I have __init__.py file in both paths :)

Comment: What does `import admin; print(admin.__file__)` give?

Comment: @AnandSKumar  `code`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PRJ/admin/web/scipt.py", line 25, in <module>
    import admin
  File "/home/user/PRJ/admin/web/admin/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from settings.custom_settings import db, Role, User
ImportError: No module named 'settings'`code`

Comment: Put the line I asked as first line, otherwise your code will keep erroring out at your place :-O

Comment: if `__init__.py` is not empty; you should include its code (the minimal code fragment that demonstrates the issue). It looks like a cyclic import issue unless there is a trivial error in `__init__.py`

Comment: File `/home/user/PRJ/web/admin/__init__.py`, beginning of line 19: isn't the `from` missing?